# Spring data solr & Solr cloud support

Tags: solrcloud, spring-data-solr

We want to introduce Solr cloud into our project, which is based on Spring-data-rest. Unfortunately we are unable to find any claims if clusterized Solr-Cloud is supported in spring data rest and we've seen plenty of issues with older spring-data and SolrCloud versions.

Are those issues resolved? Or it is not advisable to use this combination?